# StaticLiveServerTestCase not serving static files that are served fine with runserver

Tags: django

I am trying to run some selenium tests on my django app using the [`StaticLiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase). I can see when the page shows up that none of the css/javscript files or images are loading. I thought that it worked the same way as when static files are served when using `runserver` but that seems to work fine.

Is there any reason why the two would behave differently?

I can use the regular `LiveServerTestCase` but it means I have to run collectstatic every time before I run my tests which I don't really want to do if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: That's strange... `StaticLiveServerTestCase` should server the static files without the need for running `collectstatic` - that's the entire point of it. Can you show a setup that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this was actually pretty simple and not really to do with `StaticLiveServerTestCase`. I realised I am also using `ManifestStaticFileStorage` which explicitly says in its [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) that it shouldn't be used in testing. This is because it requires you to run `collectstatic` in order to generate the hashed file names. That explains why it was working combined with `LiveServerTestCase` too.